# Crowdsale contract problem

Tags: solidity, ether, crowdsale

I want to do that if another token arrives on a contract, it can be taken out by the other token.

```
function withdrawTeamSale() public {
        require(IBEP20(address(this)).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), balanceMapTeam[msg.sender]), 'Failed to transfer tokens!');
    }
```

Return:

```
Internal JSON-RPC error. { "code": -32000, "message": "execution reverted" }
```

it seems like a pretty basic thing, I must have overlooked something.

What could be the problem?

Thanks in advance for the answers!